# Calling PHP file from jQuery not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, call, execute

I am trying to execute an entire PHP file via the onClick event of some link.

```
<a onClick="phpSubmit();" class="submitButton">Submit</a>
```

Makes a successful call to this jQuery function

```
function phpSubmit()
{
    alert('submitting');

    $.post("/submit.php");

    alert('submitted'); 
}
```

Which fails to execute the PHP file "submit.php", in the same directory.

Any ideas?

I have tried $.ajax, $.get and "submit.php" as well as "/submit.php". I don't know why this isn't working, repost $.ajax stuff if you think I was doing something wrong.

**EDIT:**

It's always the little things, I mistyped a character when I imported the jQuery script which is why $.ajax was undefined.

The above method **WORKS**.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the requests (NET) through Firebug ?

Comment: Do you have try to catch the error with $.ajax()?

Comment: With Google Chrome (or Firefox with Firebug) try: right-lick open Inspect Elements >> Tab Network >> Reload >> Trigger the function. You will see the full path of what you are trying to send.

Comment: Ah yes, there is an error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Occuring on the $.ajax line

Comment: have you include jquery.js in your HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use $.post I prefer, and find it much easier for debugging, to use something like:

```
$.ajax({
   dataType: 'html',
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'submit.php',
   cache: false,
   data: 'foo=bar',
   error: function(e){
      alert(e.status);
   },
   success: function(response){
      alert(response);
   }
});
```

I would also suggest removing the `/` in front of `submit.php` - no need if it's in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

use  `$.post("submit.php");` without a slash

Answer (score 0):

You can get the error message if fail to post the data to PHP file. use $.ajax();

```
          error : function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,ErrorThrown)
          {
                alert(textStatus);
          }
```