# JQuery cannot call PHP file in hidden directory

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am having an issue with a block of JQuery that I am using to load some data from a MySQL database.

The JQuery code is calling a PHP file that sites outside of the public_html folder (which I am guessing is the problem, but cannot fix!).

**Site Structure:**

> - public_HTML < Where my domain is pointing
>
>   - /index.php
> - resources
>
>   - /config.php
>   - /functions
>
>     - /fetch-videos.php
>     - /functions.php

The JQuery sits in index.php and is calling fetch-videos.php.

I have tried moving fetch-videos.php to the public_html folder as I assumed it was because Javascript cannot see the file, but this did not work.

It's worth noting that it all works perfectly in my WAMP environment, so I assume it's an access issue with how I've structured my site online.

I want to try and keep my PHP files protected as I've been told this is wise, but can't see how I can call them from the JQuery and achieve this.

**JQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var track_click = 0; 

    var total_pages = <?php echo $total_pages; ?>;

    var fetch_path = "resources/functions/fetch_videos.php";

    $('#results').load(fetch_path, {'page':track_click, 'source': 'index'}, function() {track_click++;}); 

    $(".btn-load-more").click(function (e) { 

      $(this).hide(); 
      $('.animation_image').show(); 

      if(track_click <= total_pages) 
      {

        $.post(fetch_path,{'page': track_click, 'source': 'index'}, function(data) {

        $(".btn-load-more").show(); 

        $("#results").append(data); 

        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#load_more_button").offset().top}, 500);

        $('.animation_image').hide();

        track_click++; 

        }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
          alert(thrownError); //alert any HTTP error
          $(".btn-load-more").show(); //bring back load more button
          $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received
        });

         }

        });
    });
```

**fetch-videos.php**

```
    <?php
require_once("../config.php");
require_once("../sql_statements.php");
require_once(FUNCTIONS_PATH . "/functions.php");
$item_per_page = 10;
//sanitize post value
$page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$source = $_POST["source"];
if($source == 'category'){
    $category = $_POST["category"];
    $item_per_page = 15;
}

//throw HTTP error if page number is not valid
if(!is_numeric($page_number)){
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Invalid page number!');
    exit();
}

//get current starting point of records
$position = ($page_number * $item_per_page);

//Limit our results within a specified range.
if($source == 'index'){
    $rows = db_select(SELECT_LATEST_INDEX . " LIMIT $position, $item_per_page");
}
if($source == 'category'){
    $query = str_replace("<<category>>",$category,SELECT_LATEST_CATEGORY);
    $rows = db_select($query . " LIMIT $position, $item_per_page");
}
//output results from database
?>

<?PHP
$i = 1;
if($page_number > 0){


}
foreach ($rows as $row){

    $video_id = $row['vID'];
    $video_title = $row['Title'];
    $video_Source = $row['Source'];
    $video_SourceID = $row['SourceID'];
    $video_uploader = $row['User'];
    $video_score = $row['Likes'];
    $video_category = $row['Catgeory'];

    include(TEMPLATES_PATH . "/video-thumb.php"); 

    $i++;
}

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am all out of ideas!

Many thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**

I have heeded the advice of many and scrapped trying to protect my PHP files and restructured my site as follows:

> - public_HTML < Where my domain is pointing
>
>   - /resources
>   - /config.php
>   - /functions
>
>     - /fetch-videos.php
>     - /functions.php
>   - /index.php

Now everything is accessible to the client, I have re-run and seen the following error in the Console of Chrome Developer Tools:

```
jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4 POST http://www.*********.com/resources/functions/fetch_videos.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
send    @   jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4
ajax    @   jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4
m.fn.load   @   jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4
(anonymous) @   (index):257
j   @   jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
fireWith    @   jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
ready   @   jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
J   @   jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
```

I have updated the code above to reflect the new paths.

Thanks

Comment: If the file is outside of the web server's root folder then it can't be accessed through the web server.  When you "protect your PHP" by making it inaccessible, it becomes inaccessible.  You can't access something that you've made inaccessible.

Comment: That won't work. An ajax call is simply a http request that goes through the web server, just like an ordinary request.

Comment: This sounds like an **[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/360627)** to me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608850/calling-php-file-from-jquery-not-working

Comment: Hi - appreciate your comments, I included what I had already tried to remedy the problem to try and give a better picture of the problem.

I understand that "protecting" the PHP files makes them inaccessible, but is there a way I can get around this? Sorry if that's a silly question

Comment: Probably the files in resources are included by other PHP files.  You could create a small stub php in public_html that also includes fetch_videos.

Comment: @MartinD: When you tried to put the PHP file in the web folder, what specifically was the problem?  How was it failing?  As for the question itself, "get around" what?  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  There's no way to "get around" accessing something that you've explicitly made inaccessible.  But there might be a way to do whatever it is you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @David - Excuse the lack of detail on the problem, there is no error message being shown or anything so hard for me to explain. But I'll try! 
I am trying to structure my site in such a way that my functions etc are not in the public folder  (I've heard that's a good idea). But when I do this, the JavaScript can't see it (obviously). When I moved the "fetch_videos.php" to the public folder, there was no behavior change at all. Nothing was loaded. It worked both ways in my WAMP environment, so I am truly stumped.

Comment: @MartinD: It sounds like you should be focusing on the problem of when you make the code accessible and it still doesn't work.  Because what you're presenting here is a no-go from the start.  Regardless of how you're interpreting what you may have heard, when you make your code inaccessible from the client then the client can't access it.  By definition.

Comment: You have to put your file into `public_html` folder if you want to call it from AJAX, you need also to fix the `require_once` lines to the new path and it should work fine. If your development and production are the same, you should be able to debug any errors in your development environment.

Comment: @AhmedEssam

I have made all files accessible to the client per your advice and updated my post with the error I am receiving.

Thanks

Comment: An Internal Server Error _always_ means you got to check your server log files, and/or configure PHP to output error messages. (Go read up on that, if you don't know how.) In this case I might suspect that you might have failed to modify the path to one of your include files when moving files to different folders, and `require` throws a fatal error in such cases.

Comment: @CBroe - Thanks for your response, I went and looked in the Server Log files and disovered a bad reference!

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the  `fetch_videos.php` inside the public folder of the WEB Server. Try to load the file directly in the browser.

Note the `fetch_path` uses `..` which is NOT recommended. Use the full path instead.

```
var fetch_path = "/resources/functions/fetch_videos.php";
```

If not working, try to use the Debugger of Chrome browser (CTRL+SHIFT+I to open it usually) and check the results in the "Network". Filter by `XHR` (Ajax queries) if necessary. You should get the missing information to resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your response.
When i tried to move the fetch_videos.php to the public_html folder it still did not work. Is that because within that php file I am still trying to access files outside the public folder? I don't want to move everything into public if possible (I've read that is a bad idea!)

Comment: Hi - I followed your advice and looked in the debugger, network, AHR and saw the following error:

Internal Server Error - Read

`The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Reference #3.9d55ee3f.1501617458.4f9d72`

Thanks

Comment: Seems the problem is inside the PHP code itself. Have you updated the path in the code (such `require_once(__DIR__."/../resources/config.php");`). Also try to look inside Apache log files (`error.log` or something similar, you have to check your Apache configuration).